# Object Not found in file upload PHP

Tags: php, post, upload

Im trying to upload a file but i keep getting the sent to an object not found page error 404.

Im guessing that it is due to my path directory being wrong and the error exist between 'localhost' and C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP

Thanks in advance

My PHP code

```
<?php

$target_dir = "..\upload";
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$uploadError = "Error";
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
  }


    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
    $uploadError = "Sorry, file already exists.";}

    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 100000) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
    $uploadError = "Sorry, your file is too large.";}

    if($fileType != "txt" ) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
        $uploadError = "Sorry, only NOW TXT files are allowed.";}

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo $uploadError;} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}}?>
```

My HTML

`<form action=".php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

`action=".php"`

To :

`action=""`

(To redirect to your current page by default)

`404` means the page where you redirected wasn't found after submitting the form. The value ".php" isn't good.

Comment: Im an idiot. Thank you so much

Comment: Errors happens to everyone. You're welcome. Feel free to validate the answer.